# infinite loop creating 90,000 random files ..but it creates only 10?

Tags: php, file, loops, infinite

when out of ideas, thou shall turn to stackoverflow. so that's what i'm doing :) i need to fill up a directory with 90,000 random files (no content needed) but for some reason, my infinite loop script is only creating about 10 files (from 1-10) and nothing more. what am i doing wrong?

```
 <?
 $counter = 1;
 while ($counter < 90000) {
 $rand = rand(1, 9999999999999999999999);
 print (" counter = " . $counter . "<BR>");
 $ourFileName = "$rand";
 $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
 fclose($ourFileHandle);
 $counter++;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Consider the limits of integer values in 32-bit PHP... then why on earth do you need 90,000 (way too many to be sensible for a directory) randomly named empty files.

Comment: Why not use for loop? `for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter < 90000 ; $counter++)`. Won't fix anything, but least its more readable.

Comment: Can anyone give me just one practical use for this code?

Comment: why downvote this? you may think the code or purpose is bad, but that doesn't make a bad question. +1 to compensate.

Comment: The reason isn't malicious or bad, but I need to test another script and if it can handle 90,000 files or not. Instead of creating 90,000 files manually I thought it's easier to do it with a PHP script. Any better ideas to fill a directory with 90,000 files?

Answer (score 2):

Here's why:

```
php > $x = 9999999999999999999999;
php > echo $x;
1.0E+22
php > echo rand(1, 9999999999999999999999);
1
php > echo rand(1, 9999999999999999999999);
1
php > echo rand(1, 9999999999999999999999);
1
php > echo rand(1, $x);
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$NoOfFiles = 10;

for($i = 0; $i < $NoOfFiles; $i++){
    $FileHandler = fopen($i.".txt", 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fclose($FileHandler);
    echo "File '". $i.".txt' has been created<br/>";
}
```

Just alter the $NoOfFiles variable to however many files you want creating...